# Solaris zone public IP

Tags: oracle, solaris, solaris-10

I've configured zone with exclusive ip and it's accessible via SSH from solaris host but not from worldwide.
How can I make zone be accessible from other devices, not only from solaris host?

Thanks

Comment: Ask this in http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This will require super user privilege.

1. Login to the non-global XIP(exclusive IP) solaris zone:
   # zlogin -C 
   Where, myzone is the non-global exclusive IP solaris zone.
2. Within the non-global zone, as 'root', execute the below command to configure the system.

# sysconfig configure

You will land into the Solaris system configure tool.

3. When prompted for the system name, provide a valid hostname for the non-global zone. For e.g., vzmyzone.example.com
   You can validate that such a hostname is resolvable by executing the below command from the global zone.
   # nslookup vzmyzone.example.com
4. When prompted for Networking specifications, choose 'Manual' option and provide the information such as IP address of the non-global zone, netmask, default router IP.
5. When prompted for the naming service, choose among DNS, NIS, LDAP and provide relevant information.
   For e.g., if you choose DNS; then provide at least one valid IP address for the DNS server or servers to be used by the system. and at least one valid domain name to be searched when a DNS query is made.

Once, all configuration has been done, system will reboot and you shall be able to access the non-global XIP zone worldwide (within your network).

Note: Ensure you have correctly setup the subnet mask value for the nic during the zone configuration using zonecfg command.